# Benchmark express apis with autocannon from postman collection

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I need to benchmark all my express apis.
I found this [package](https://github.com/mcollina/autocannon) on github. Examples are listed only for one get request.

There are also some other samples for other requests as well.

I want to know should I create a separate script for all the APIs and run them once.

I already have a postman collection for all the APIs. Is there any way I can use that to benchmark them?

If there is any other way to benchmark express APIs, please suggest.

**Update**

```
const autocannon = require("autocannon");
const fs = require("fs");

const collection = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./customer-apis-v1.3.2.json", "UTF-8"));
const requests = collection.item;

(async function test() {
  for (const request of requests) {
    console.log(`Testing ${request.name}`);
    for (const item of request.item) {
      const result = await autocannon({
        title: item.name,
        url: item.request.url.raw,
        method: item.request.method,
      });
      autocannon.printResult(result);
    }
  }
})().catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export your Postman Collection as JSON.

1. Right Click on the collection
2. Click `export`
3. Choose Collection type
4. Click `export`

The exported file will be a `.json` file and will look like this:

```json
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "...",
        "name": "...",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "name",
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://...",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        ...
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        ...
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "...",
                            "value": "..."
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ],
    "protocolProfileBehavior": {}
}
```

Then you can [use autocannon programatically](https://github.com/mcollina/autocannon#programmatically) and read the json file

```js
const autocannon = require("autocannon");
const fs = require("fs");

// read array of items from exported .json file from postman
const requests = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("path/to/postman/exported.json", "UTF-8")).items; 

async function test() {
  for (const item of requests) {
    // test request using autocannon, pass the method, body, etc. on the autocannon options
    // you might need to manipulate your data in item so you can pass it to autocannon
    
    console.log(`Testing ${item.name}`);

    const result = await autocannon({
      url: item.request.url.raw,
      method: item.request.method,
      ... // read other options here: https://github.com/mcollina/autocannon#autocannonopts-cb
    })
    console.log(result);
    // or print table
    autocannon.printResult(result);
  }
}
```

You can also do it without await

---

The other way is to use Postman built-in Testing utility

1. Right click on the collection
2. Click `Edit`
3. Click `Tests` tab
4. Write your test script there

Doc about writing test: https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/test-scripts/

Doc about monitoring test performance: https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/monitoring-your-api/intro-monitors/

Comment: You answer really helped. I am having one problem. With this script I am not getting tabular results, instead getting `JSON` on console. Is there any method I can get the table wise data for each test?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/mcollina/autocannon#autocannonprintresultresultobject-opts)? You can print the result tables to the terminal programmatically instead of using `console.log`, I assume it will look like this `autocannon.printResult(result)` on the for loop

Comment: I tried that but getting this errorr `typeerror: autocannon.printresult is not a function`. I have updated the question and have included the code that I am trying with. My postman collection contain requests inside a folder so `collection.json > auth > requests` also `collection.json > order > requests`

Comment: There was an issue, before version `6.6` they were using `printResult` only internally, it wasn't exposed. It was only exposed on `6.6` which is current release and they haven't updated the npm yet. I am using package directly from git. https://github.com/mcollina/autocannon/pull/297 https://github.com/mcollina/autocannon/compare/v6.6.0...master  But still it's printing the table.

Comment: Fixed it finally, turned out they are not using `printResult` to log on screen, instead returning table as string which I need to `console.log`